# Make mac mail VIP lists include items I send

Tags: mail.app

The VIP lists in Mac Mail don't seem to include emails I sent to a VIP that aren't part of a conversation. If I send an email with a new subject (ie: not a reply), it doesn't appear until the recipient replies (in which case the whole thread appears, including the one I originally sent).

Is there a way to get these messages to appear in te VIP lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there does not seem to be a way to include sent email in the VIP mailbox.

According to Apple's [Mail User Guide – Show emails from VIP senders in Mail on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/show-emails-from-vip-senders-mail40589/mac): "Any messages in the Inbox **from**  a VIP (even sent as part of a conversation) are displayed in a VIP mailbox." *[emphasis added]*

The conditions for Smart Mailboxes also only offer `Sender is VIP` and `Sender is member of group`.

However, you can create a new Smart Mailbox in the Mail app and add conditions of type `Any recipient is equal to` and manually add conditions with VIP email addresses to that Smart Mailbox. This way you could have a Smart Mailbox where mails you send to those recipients appear.

See also Apple's [Mail User Guide – Use Smart Mailboxes in Mail on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-smart-mailboxes-mlhlp1190/mac)